# finding when a file was introduced on github

Tags: github

This curl command works as expected and shows when the repository was first created.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/RaRe-Technologies/gensim | grep created

"created_at": "2011-02-10T07:43:04Z",
```

But this does not show when a file in that repo was created.

> curl
> https://api.github.com/repos/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/scripts/make_wikicorpus.py
> | grep created

Is there any way to find the date on which the file was introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits?path=<path/to/file>`, as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#list-commits-on-a-repository).

The results of this request can then be parsed by [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), with the following options `.[-1].commit.author.date`.
This tells `jq` to get the last item of the array (`[-1]`), and then parse the value of `commit`, then `author` and then the `date`, which is the date of the commit.

So using the follwing command

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commits?path=gensim/scripts/make_wikicor
pus.py" | jq -r ".[-1].commit.author.date"
```

will result in

```
2012-07-21T20:00:29Z
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative, using [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/), and its [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) command:

```
# Windows
gh api -X GET repos/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commits \
       -f path="gensim/scripts/make_wikicorpus.py" \
       --jq ".[-1].commit.author.date"

# Linux
gh api -X GET repos/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commits \
       -f path='gensim/scripts/make_wikicorpus.py' \
       --jq '.[-1].commit.author.date'

2012-07-21T20:00:29Z
```

You don't even need `jq` if you have [`gh` installed](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=).